# pyodbc cannot find driverfile for PostgreSQL (when it exists)

Tags: postgresql, odbc, pyodbc, centos8

I have a CentOS 8 server and I try to connect to a PostgreSQL DB.

My python-file looks like

```py
def read_df(query):
        """
        Function for fetching data from the DB.
        """

        con_str = (
            "DRIVER={PostgreSQL};"
            "DATABASE=db;"
            f"UID={user};"
            f"PWD={pwd};"
            f"SERVER={host};"
            f"PORT={port};"
            )

        with pyodbc.connect(con_str) as con:
            df = pd.read_sql(query,con=con)
        return df
```

and `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[PostgreSQL]
Driver = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64 = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64 = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
```

the files specified above do exist:

```
>ls /usr/lib64 | grep psq
psqlodbcw.so
psqlodbca.so
psqlodbc.so
libodbcpsqlS.so
```

and I can access the file

```
with open("/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so","r") as f:
      print("It works")

"It works"
```

but running `read_df` throws

```
  File "/home/user/db_connect.py", line 192, in read_df
    with pyodbc.connect(con_str) as con:
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I can see the file also from python `import os; os.listdir("/usr/lib64")` - and am completely lost.

EDIT: Running `ldd /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so` yields

```sh
$ ldd /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce158b000)
        libpq.so.5 => /lib64/libpq.so.5 (0x00007f1e90be1000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1e909c1000)
        libodbcinst.so.2 => /lib64/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f1e907ab000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1e903e6000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f1e90152000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f1e8fc6c000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f1e8fa17000)
        libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f1e8f7c0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1e910bb000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /lib64/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f1e8f5b6000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1e8f39f000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1e8f19b000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f1e8eeb2000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f1e8ec9b000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f1e8ea97000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f1e8e886000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f1e8e682000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f1e8e46b000)
        liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f1e8e25b000)
        libsasl2.so.3 => /lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007f1e8e03d000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f1e8de13000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f1e8dbea000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f1e8d966000)
```

Comment: Do you see any potential problems if you do `ldd /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so`  ?

Comment: Don't know - it does print some some lines e.g `libpq.so.5 => /lib64/libpq.so.5 (0x00007f999a220000)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete output.

Comment: I have added the full output now

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing exactly the same.